# Python- how to create a function that splits data into train and validation using scikit

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sysbp':[106,121,121,105,108], 
                'diabp':[70,66,81,69,66], 
                'totchol':[195,209,250,260,237],
                'ANYCHD':[1,1,0,0,0]})
```

ANYCHD is the y variable.

I have to write a function that will split my data into train and validation sets. I have managed to split the data without a function using:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x, y, z, g = train_test_split(fr, fr['ANYCHD'], test_size = .2)
```

I have been asked that the function only take in 2 arguments: df and size.

I have tried:

```
def split_set(df, size):
    """ 
    df: DataFrame to split
    size: proportion of data to allocate to validation set (same as train_test_split's test_size)
    """
    train.x, train.y, test.x, test.y = train_test_split(df, df[""], size)
    return train.x, train.y, test.x, test.y 

fr_train, fr_val, y_train, y_val = split_set(fr, fr['ANYCHD'])
```

I can't change the def statement to take parameters other than df and size, however, the rest of the code I can change.

Currently, I am having trouble with the function only taking 2 arguments and the train_test_split taking 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is ANYCHD always the y variable? If yes then the solution is very simple:

```
def split_set(df, size):
    """ 
    df: DataFrame to split
    size: proportion of data to allocate to validation set (same as train_test_split's test_size)
    """
    train.x, train.y, test.x, test.y = train_test_split(df, df['ANYCHD'], test_size = .2) 
    return train.x, train.y, test.x, test.y 

fr_train, fr_val, y_train, y_val = split_set(fr, .2)
```

You just hardcode the Y information ('ANYCHD') in the call to train_test_split.

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like it should work, but I get the error message TypeError: Singleton array array(0.2) cannot be considered a valid collection. Do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: Try now! I just added the argument name test_size in the split call.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you are trying to implement your own version of train_test split, you could do something like

```
def split_data(df, size):
    train_idx = np.random.choice(df.index, int(len(df)*size), replace = False)
    test_idx = np.setdiff1d(df.index, train_idx)
    train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y = df.iloc[train_idx, :-1], df.iloc[train_idx, -1], df.iloc[test_idx, :-1], df.iloc[test_idx, -1]
    return train_x, train_y, test_x, test_y

split_data(df, .8)

(   sysbp  diabp  totchol
 4    108     66      237
 2    121     81      250
 3    105     69      260
 1    121     66      209, 
 4    0
 2    0
 3    0
 1    1
 Name: ANYCHD, dtype: int64,    sysbp  diabp  totchol
 0    106     70      195, 0    1
 Name: ANYCHD, dtype: int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def split_set(df, size):
    """ 
    df: DataFrame to split
    size: proportion of data to allocate to validation set (same as train_test_split's test_size)
    """
    return train_test_split(df[['SYSBP', 'DIABP', 'TOTCHOL', 'DIABETES', 'CURSMOKE', 'BPMEDS']], df['ANYCHD'], test_size = size)


fr_train, fr_val, y_train, y_val = split_set(fr, .2) 
fr_train.shape, fr_val.shape
```